# Javascript Debounce not clearing it's queue from vue component

Tags: javascript, scope, debouncing

I am using the debounce method from here https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-debounce-example/

```
function debounce(func, timeout = 300){
  let timer;
  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => { func.apply(this, args); }, timeout);
  };
}
function saveInput(){
  console.log('Saving data');
}
const processChange = debounce(() => saveInput());
```

and I want to include in a library we have, so in `common.js` I have:

```
export default {
  otherStuff,
  debounce(func, timeout = 300) {
    let timer;
    return (...args) => {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = setTimeout(() => {
        func.apply(this, args);
      }, timeout);
    };
  },
```

in vue.js I have a textbox which has an event `@keyup="searchboxChange()"`

and in the methods section:

```
import common from "@/assets/js/Service/Common";
... stuff removed for brevity
methods:
  {
    searchboxChange(){
      common.debounce(() => this.filterChanged(), 1000)();
    },
  }
```

I had to include () at the end of the debounce method else it didn't actually fire. However, while it debounces perfectly, when the timeout expires every event is then fired. So if my search was "HELLO" I would see 5 requests all fired at the same time as `this.filterChanged()` was called 5 times.

I am sure it is something simple with the scope of the timeout variable, because adding a console.log into the debounce method shows the timer is undefined each time.

Comment: Have you tried implementing a leading debounce?

Comment: Because you're not debouncing your component method but instead debouncing a function inside the method `searchboxChange` you're actually invoking a new debounced function each time. One approach I take it to debounce the component method like `searchboxChange: common.debounce(() => doSomething(), 1000)` - This ensures the component method is debounced however you may run into context issues with `this` so be mindful of that

Comment: thank you for the swift reply. I have changed it and as expected, issues with this.filterChanged() where this is undefined. on the positive, I replaced the function with a console.log and it only appeared once!

Comment: Check my answer regarding the lexical scope of `this`

Comment: Can you try it like this: ` searchboxChange: common.debounce(this.filterChanged(), 1000)`? I don't think that you need the callback, you should be able to pass the function directly with this *debounce* implementation.

Comment: I will give that a try tomorrow morning, there is a chance it is one of the combinations I have not tried! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, as always, thanks to everyone who contributed a solution. However, none got past the "this" is not the right scope.

The solution was to set the function in created. (source: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/lodash-debounce-not-working-when-placed-inside-a-method/86334/4)

which (in case link goes dead) is effectively saying

> move the part that you need to debounce into its own method and debounce that (like you did in the codepen for he first method).
>
> Then you can call the debounced method from the event handler method.
>
> It’s also better to debounce each instance method dynamically during created, otherwise component instances that the same debounced function and that can lead to wonky debounce behaviour:

and their code sample:

```
created() {
  this.updateForm = _.debounce(this.updateForm, 500)
},
methods: {
    triggerUpdate(event){
      // perform some action before debouncing
     this.updateForm(event)
    } ,
    updateForm: (event){
     console.log('in update')
    }
```

so for my case:

```
  created() {
    this.searchboxChange = common.debounce(this.filterChanged, 1000)
  },
```

yes, that is literally it.

result:
[image: network traffic showing only one call]

only one network call now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to debounce the component method, otherwise you'll be invoking multiple debounced functions from within your component method.

Something like this should work

```
methods: {
  // ...
  searchboxChange: common.debounce(function() {
    this.filterChanged();
  }, 1000)
}
```

Notice the use of `function` as opposed to short function syntax. You'll need to do this to ensure the correct lexical scope of `this`

Comment: Thanks again - sadly `this` is scoped to the common component, rather than the vue model.